# I have divided my page using grid .Its a rowise grid of 1fr 8fr 1fr but the division is not till footer it is showing white space

Tags: html, css

I am making a web page in which i divided the page in 3 rows using css grid of fractions:1fr 8fr 1fr but the page is not divided fully and showing whitespace in footer which. should not be there ,the footer sholud cover the end page

Answer (score 0):

If `body` is your grid container, do :

**CSS**

```
body {
  min-height : 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

`min-height : 100vh` means that your container should be at least the height of the screen.
**BUT** without a minimal code example coming from you I can't be 100% sure that it will solve your problem.

Comment: If it solved your problem, think about accepting the answer ;) @AsthaTyagi